# Vpaid iframe freezes on Chrome when unmuting the video in google ima sdk player

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

For playing our VPAID unit in Google IMA SDK player, we create an iframe. The video is autoplayed and set muted. when trying to unmute the video using SDK player, since the button is located on the parent iframe, there is no user interaction with our iframe, that's why on Chrome we get the error,

> Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before

and the video freezes.

We tried different solutions like using a friendly iframe, mocking the user interaction, etc, but none is working. If anybody has any solution please don't hesitate. Thank you..

[image: The image shows how our iframe which is underlined with yellow line is placed]

[image: The video freezes when unmuting by SDK player mute/unmute button]

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as image...

Comment: The image is the Element part of dev tool related to Google IMA SDK player tester page. Showing the relation between our iframe( underlined with yellow), and the video control buttons ( blue line) in the google ima sdk iframe.